# Comparing values sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table wherein I have to report the the present status and the date from which this status is applicable. 
Example:

```
Status   date
1        26 July
1        24 July
1        22 July
2        21 July
2        19 July
1        16 July
0        14 July
```

Given this, i want to display the current status as 1 and date as 22 July> I am not sure how to go about this.

```
Status   date
    1        25 July
    1        24 July
    1        20 July
```

In this case, I want to show the status as 1 and date as 20th July

Comment: What is the logic for the remaining values? What will status be when the date is < '2012-07-22'? Are you simply looking for a select statement?

Comment: You're going to need to have multiple subqueries, as you're going to need to determine the maximum date, the status attached with that date, and then the minimum date attached to that status with no different statuses after.  What do you have so far?

Comment: Does this table have a primary or unique key?

Comment: It means that the status is updated with the ongoing improvements on that particular day. if there is no update that means, the previous status holds good for the present day too.. i have it ordered in this way at present..

Answer (score 1):

This should pull what you need using very standard SQL:

```
-- Get the oldest date that is the current Status
select Status, min(date) as date
from MyTable
where date > (
    -- Get the most recent date that isn't the current Status
    select max(date)
    from MyTable
    where Status != (
        -- Get the current Status
        select Status -- May need max/min here for multiple statuses on same date
        from MyTable
        where date = (
            -- Get the most recent date
            select max(date)
            from MyTable
        )
    )
)
group by Status
```

I'm assuming that the `date` column is of a data type suitable for sorting properly (as in, not a string, unless you can cast it).

Comment: Thank you. Its of date type, not a string

Answer (score 0):

This is a little inelegant, but it should work

```
SELECT status, date
FROM my_table t
WHERE status = ALL (SELECT status
                    FROM my_table
                    WHERE date = ALL(SELECT MAX(date) FROM my_table))
AND date = ALL (SELECT MIN(date) 
                FROM my_table t1
                WHERE t1.status = t.status 
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                  FROM my_table t2 
                                  WHERE t2.date > t1.date AND t2.status <> t1.status))
```

Comment: That's odd.  I tried it with the values you gave in your question and it worked fine for me.  Could you give a sample of the input you ran it on?

Comment: Date           Status
7/25/2012 1
7/16/2012 1
7/9/2012 1
6/28/2012 1
6/25/2012 1
6/19/2012 2
6/12/2012 2
6/8/2012 2
6/5/2012 2
5/30/2012 2
5/23/2012 2
5/17/2012 2
5/8/2012 2
5/2/2012 1
4/24/2012 2
4/12/2012 2
4/9/2012 2
3/21/2012 2
6/25/2012 1
6/19/2012 2
6/12/2012 2
6/8/2012 2
6/5/2012 2
5/30/2012 2
5/23/2012 2
5/17/2012 2
5/8/2012 2
5/2/2012 1
4/24/2012 2
4/12/2012 2
4/9/2012 2
3/21/2012 2

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a window function like `LEAD` (or `LAG` depending on how you order your results). In this example we mark the row when the status changes with the date, order the results and exclude rows other than the first one:

```
with test_data as (
      select 1 status, date '2012-07-26' status_date from dual union all
      select 1 status, date '2012-07-24' status_date from dual union all
      select 1 status, date '2012-07-22' status_date from dual union all
      select 2 status, date '2012-07-21' status_date from dual union all
      select 2 status, date '2012-07-19' status_date from dual union all
      select 1 status, date '2012-07-16' status_date from dual union all
      select 0 status, date '2012-07-14' status_date from dual)

select status, as_of
from (
    select status
    , case when status != lead(status) over (order by status_date desc) then status_date else null end as_of
    from test_data
    order by as_of desc nulls last
    )
where rownum = 1;
```

**Addendum:**
The `LEAD` and `LAG` functions accept two more parameters: `offset` and `default`. The `offset` defaults to 1, and `default` defaults to null. The default allows you to determine what value to consider when you are at the beginning or end of the result set. In your case when the status has never changed, a default is needed. In this example I supplied -1 as a status default because I am assuming that status value is not part of your expected set:

```
with test_data as (
      select 1 status, date '2012-07-25' status_date from dual union all
      select 1 status, date '2012-07-24' status_date from dual union all
      select 1 status, date '2012-07-20' status_date from dual)

select status, as_of
from (
    select status
    , case when status != lead(status,1,-1) over (order by status_date desc) then status_date else null end as_of
    from test_data
    order by as_of desc nulls last
    )
where rownum = 1;
```

You can play around with the case condition (equals/not equals), the order by clause in the lead function, and the desired default to accomplish your needs.

Comment: Nice. I usually write a query a couple of different ways when one option is to use window functions, because I _almost never_ know which will be faster.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not aware of lead and lag window functions :)

Comment: Hi Wolf.. this works absolutely fine when a status change has occured.. But when there is no status change and I want to report the date from which the present status is valid, it gives me a null value.. I tried modifying it but was not getting the correct result.. Ex: 1 22-July 1 20-July.. In this case, I need 1 from 20th july.. How do I fit it in this code..? Thanks

Comment: @Sindhu I'm not sure if I understand. Are you expecting one row? From your sample data the status '1' is in effect as of July 22, but on July 20 the status is '2'. Could you edit your post and include a code block showing what results you are expecting (similar to your sample data)?

Comment: @ Wolf : This a particular case. Here the status always remains the same. I have to report the date from which the status is in effect. <br/>

Comment: @wolf: Sorry about the incomplete comment previously. I have modified the post. Can I accomplish the 2nd scenario listed in the above post with the lead/lag functions? How do you suggest me to go about this. thank you so much for your help and time!

Comment: @Sindhu I updated my answer. LEAD also accepts an offset and a default. I think you need an appropriate status default for this case when the status has never changed.

Comment: @wolf: Thanks a lot for all the guidance and help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Sindhu I'm glad to help. Don't forget to up vote or accept the correct answer when you have finished your analysis.